# How do I compare 2 files with the same name in iOS to check if they are copies of the same file or different files

Tags: ios, filesystems, icloud

I am using UIDocument to save a document file to the local storage sandbox in the Documents directory. I have another file in iCloud with the same name. How would I check if those two files are copies of the same document file or two different document files with the same name?

Using NSFileVersion doesn't tell me if they are the same file, just what version of the file it is.

I tried getting the resource values of the files, but the file in the local storage sandbox gives me nil as the document identifier.

Here is code using the documentIdentifier resource value:

```
    let localFileResourceValues = try? self.document!.fileURL.resourceValues(forKeys: [URLResourceKey.documentIdentifierKey])

    let iCloudFileResourceValues = try? destinationURL.resourceValues(forKeys: [URLResourceKey.documentIdentifierKey])

    print("documentIdentifier", localFileResourceValues?.documentIdentifier as Any, iCloudFileResourceValues?.documentIdentifier as Any, localFileResourceValues?.documentIdentifier == iCloudFileResourceValues?.documentIdentifier)
```

Print results:

> documentIdentifier nil Optional(133819) false

Is it possible to get an NSMetadataItem from a file in the local storage sandbox?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

To find out if the two file paths point to the same file object, you need to normalise the file paths by using `NSString stringByStandardizingPath`, then resolve symbolic links by using `NSString stringByResolvingSymlinksInPath:`, and then compare the paths. [This web page](https://digitalleaves.com/blog/2013/09/nsurl-files-equality-comparison-and-equivalency/) has a good description and ready-to-go code.

To find out whether two files have the same contents, even while they might be different file objects, then `NSFileManager contentsEqualAtPath:andPath:` is useful.